# ImageView in Hbox won't show up in GridPane

Tags: java, javafx, imageview, gridpane

I'm making an application that shows info about cars, later i'm gonna add CRUD functionality but right now I wanna get an image to show on the gridpane.

I have a small Main-Class that just contains the start method, then I have another class with all the GUI components. Here's the GUI:

[GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rnFq5.png)

I want to make an image appear in the top-right area of the screen.

I also have a car class, from which I have created car objects and put in an array. The array holds info about brand, model, reg.nr and URL to the imagefile. I've also created get() methods in the carclass.

So i successfully added all the other components to the grid in my GUIComponents-class, and lastly i try to add this, just to try and show the first carobjects image:

```
HBox hbCarImg = new HBox();
ImageView imageView = new ImageView(new Image(carArray[0].getImageURL()));
hbCarImg.getChildren().add(imageView);
add(hbCarImg, 2, 1, 2, 3);
```

I want the hbox to appear on column 2, row 1 and span over 2 columns and 3 rows.

Nothing happens when I do this. Spent alot of time searching about this and the code seems fine, I have no idea what doesn't work.

Any tips or help is appreciated!

Comment: Did you verify that the image URL is correct and points to existing image data?

Comment: @VGR Yeah, the URL's in the array are valid!

Comment: Verify the HBox is actually in your GridPane by giving it a visible border.  For example, `hbCarImg.setStyle("-fx-border-color: red;");`

Comment: @VGR I tried that, and the box appears on screen, exactly how i want it, but still no image. [link](http://oi68.tinypic.com/10neu5l.jpg)

Comment: What is the string returned by `carArray[0].getImageURL()`?

Comment: @VGR It's just a random car image from the net: http://www.1001moteurs.com/perfs/voitures/34989.jpg , if you saw my link in earlier comment, i use the same getImageURL() method for the textfield there, and the string shows up.

Comment: That URL does not load for me.  If you enter it in a browser, does an image load?

Comment: @VGR okay this is really weird, I swear that link I just posted to you works for me, it loads and it's a pic of a Volvo. But I just tried to change url to some other photo and now i works. I feel dumb, but at the same time I wonder why the URL doesn't work. Haha well, thanks for your help anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Although is a bit long but this should do:

```
  //start with scrollpane

  ScrollPane sp = new ScrollPane();  

  //create a gridpane
  GridPane gb = new GridPane();
  gb.setHgap(5);
  gb.setVgap(5);


  //for debugging purposes, make sure you remove it
  gb.setGridLinesVisible(true);

  gb.setPadding(new Insets(10,10,10,10));
  gb.setPrefSize(600, 600);

  //initialize the number of rows and columns
  int imgCol = 0;
  int imgRow = 0;


  //i am making use of an entity bean class (POJO)
  //you can edit as you deem fit
  //create a list
  List<Info> list = rentalBn.carStatus();

  //create an String array list
  /**i stored the filepath of my images to the database 
  instead of theother way round**/
  ArrayList<String> fileArray = new ArrayList<>();
   ArrayList<String> nameArray = new ArrayList<>();
   ArrayList<String> modelArray = new ArrayList<>();
   ArrayList<String> manuArray = new ArrayList<>();
   ArrayList<Float> priceArray = new ArrayList<>();
   ArrayList<String> availArray = new ArrayList<>();


  ImageView img;

  //Use for loop to populate the arraylist with elements from the list
    for(Info inf : list){
      fileArray.add(inf.getImage());
      nameArray.add(inf.getCarname());
      modelArray.add(inf.getCarmodel());
      manuArray.add(inf.getManufacturer());
      priceArray.add(inf.getPrice());
      availArray.add(inf.getAvailable());
  }

System.out.println(fileArray.size());
System.out.println(nameArray.size());

for(int i = 0; i < fileArray.size(); i++){
     System.out.println(fileArray.get(i));
     System.out.println(nameArray.get(i));

//convert to bufferedImage
BufferedImage bi;
bi = ImageIO.read(new File(fileArray.get(i)));

//convert to FXImage
 Image image = SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(bi, null);


  img = new ImageView();
  img.setFitHeight(150);
  img.setFitHeight(150);
  img.setPreserveRatio(false);
  img.setImage(image);


 //add text below the images
 Text nameText = new Text();
 nameText.setText("Car Name: " + nameArray.get(i));

 Text modelText = new Text();
 modelText.setText("Car Model: " + modelArray.get(i));

 Text manuText = new Text();
 manuText.setText("Manufacturer: " + manuArray.get(i));

 Text priceText = new Text();
 priceText.setText("Price: " + priceArray.get(i));

 Text availText = new Text();
 availText.setText("Available: " + availArray.get(i));



 //create a VBox
  VBox hb = new VBox();
  hb.setPrefSize(150, 150);


  //add the imageView and other texts inside the box          
  hb.getChildren().addAll(img, nameText, modelText, 
  manuText, priceText, availText );                                       

 //create a pane, change the background
 Pane grid = new Pane();
 grid.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #00ff00;");
 grid.setPrefSize(200, 400);
 grid.getChildren().add(hb);

  //add the pane inside the gridpane
  gb.add(grid, imgCol, imgRow);

 //then add the gridpane inside the scrollpane
  sp.setContent(gb);

  imgCol++;

  //reset the column and row
  if(imgCol >3){
      imgCol =0;

      imgRow++;
  }

}


    Scene scene = new Scene(sp, 750, 700);


    primaryStage.setTitle("stage title");
    primaryStage.setFullScreen(false);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

you can refer to [**THIS**](http://geekshelm.com/creating-entity-bean-netbeans/) for the [**POJO/entity**](http://geekshelm.com/creating-entity-bean-netbeans) class.